# How do I find python built-in function implementations?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In order to make an educated decision, I especially need to take a look at how `range` is implemented in Python 3. How do I find this implementation?
I know I can use `module.__file__` for modules, but which modules does built-in functions belong to, and where do I find the implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always read the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Objects/rangeobject.c#l73)

Comment: I've changed the link to point to Python 3.3 source (instead of 2.7)

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for. Just couldn't find it in the source :)

Comment: hello, I'm puzzled where to find the resource file of built-in module, like `time`? almost standard lib I could find in /usr/lib/python3.x, except this one

Comment: if you are using a mac, you can open the python interpreter using `python -v` and then do `import time`. This would print out the location the module was imported from @rancho

Comment: thx, archlinux-python3.5, I got `import 'time' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>`,  what does that mean, how can I see the implement of `time` module? @karthikr